# Records are not being written or being deleted in a parent table and I don't know why with MariaDB/MySQL and PHP. Ideas?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, foreign-keys

Here is the structure of the database tables in quesiton.

Officials:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `officials` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `middle` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zip` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `homeph` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `workph` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cellph` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `main_phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `blockreg` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `inactive` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `minority` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `affiliate` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is affiliate official? 0 = no. 1 = yes.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14506 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Transactions (edited from original post to show foreign key constraints):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `offid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `txn_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `txn_time` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `approval_code` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `result_message` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ch_phone` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `ch_card_type` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `ch_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ch_state` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ch_last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ch_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ch_zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ch_exp_date` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `ch_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ch_first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ch_transaction_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ch_card_number` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `txn_id` (`txn_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `offid` (`offid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `transactions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `transactions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`offid`) REFERENCES `officials` (`id`);
```

Transaction details (edited from original post to show foreign key constraints):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transaction_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `xact_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `detail_amount` float(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `sport` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `regyr` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `xact_id` (`xact_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
ALTER TABLE `transaction_details`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `transaction_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`xact_id`) REFERENCES `transactions` (`txn_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Code that executes upon receiving the data from the credit card company where rows are inserted into the table:

```
// this creates the main transaction

    $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (offid, txn_id, txn_time, approval_code, amount, result_message, ch_phone,
                          ch_card_type, ch_address, ch_state, ch_last_name, ch_email, ch_zip, ch_exp_date, ch_city, ch_first_name,
                          ch_transaction_type, ch_card_number) VALUES ('$offid', '$txn_id', '$txn_time', '$approval_code', '$amount', '$result_message',
                                                                       '$ch_phone', '$ch_card_type', '$ch_address', '$ch_state', '$ch_last_name', '$ch_email',
                                                                       '$ch_zip', '$ch_exp_date', '$ch_city', '$ch_first_name', '$ch_transaction_type', '$ch_card_number')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// this creates the detail transactions
if ($ssl_result == 0) {
    $detail_sports = array('fb', 'vb', 'sb', 'bb', 'wr', 'sw', 'so', 'ba', 'tr');
    foreach ($detail_sports as $sport) {
        $var = $sport . 'total';
        // cookie is set for fbtotal, vbtotal, etc. with an amount for that line item
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$var])) {
            $detail_amount = $_COOKIE[$var];
            $sql           = "INSERT INTO transaction_details (xact_id, detail_amount, sport, regyr) VALUES ('$txn_id', '$detail_amount', '$sport', '$regyear')";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

The transaction table has id numbers 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, etc. These should be consecutively numbered, but they aren't. It's almost as if they were written to the transaction (parent) table and then deleted. But the code doesn't delete a record.

The transaction detail table has a many-to-one relationship with transaction and all of its records contain consecutive ids.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are there ever any failures? Such as trying to insert a duplicate, which thows a constraint violation error? Or any concurrent executions of inserts? *(Also, I **strongly** urge you to stop building queries with string substitution/concatenation. For security, maintainability, robustness, and performance reasons, you should be using prepared statements / parameterized queries.)*

Comment: It's possible to have gaps in auto increment ids if there is a rollback. Search 'sequence gaps' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: @MatBailie The only reason I know about this error is because it was deployed on June 9. The credit card company transaction list shows the missing transactions from the database, so they either never got written or they were deleted. The substitution and concatenation occur because it's a legacy system and I've just done it the way it was done for consistency and because technical debt contributes to job security (sarcasm voice).

Comment: @MarshallC I had never heard of the rollback gaps. I read your link, but that's not what's happening here. The transaction isn't being recorded (or it's being deleted after it's recorded). I'm just wondering if anyone has ever heard of anything like this happening where the parent key exists, but the foreign key seems to be deleting it. It's weird.

Comment: Your table definitions don't actually include any foreign key constraints. You may have foreign keys logically, but your question doesn't show that you've actually implemented the constraints in the database. Therefore, at present, it appears impossible for the cause to be foreign key related (as, from the database engine perspective, you don't have any foreign keys implemented). Failed inserts still feels like the likely cause to me (even if the insert fails, and the database rolls back, the id is still used up and not 'freed' during rollback).

Comment: @MatBailie I appreciate your help. Nice catch on the foreign key constraints. I just forgot to post it. I've edited the original code to show the constraints that I have on the tables. I forgot to answer your question regarding failures from your first comment, but the answer is no. I have not been able to recreate one, but obviously, something is causing this to fail. It just strikes me as odd, and I can't quite wrap my head around it, is that there are id numbers missing in the transaction table. Which makes me think something is cascading and deleting those records. contd -->

Comment: But I don't have anything in my structure or my code that would cause records to be deleted from the parent table (transactions). As you can see from my FK constraints, deleting a record from the transaction table would cascade and delete the corresponding records from the transaction_details table.

Comment: @MatBailie It took me a while to find it in the code, but in some rare instances, offid was not passed into the transactions table. So I did have failures, but was unaware of the failures. Thanks for making me dig a little deeper and look a little harder!